# How to forward a port via an IPv6 tunnel?

Tags: port-forwarding, tunneling

I have a service on port 8080 of my local machine, which I have created an IPv6 tunnel via Hurricane Electric’s service for on

https://www.tunnelbroker.net

I can ping the tunnel. So that part works, but I can’t use my service on 8080.

How can I forward or listen to the port?

Comment: You don't "forward" anything. You just connect directly to it. If you are having a problem, you should ask about that problem.

Comment: IPv6 is made for end to end-connectivity with all computers having globally routable addresses. Port Forwarding is not a concept with IPv6 in most setups. I'd advice you to take [HE's IPv6 certification](https://ipv6.he.net/certification/), which gives you a overview over the basics of IPv6.

Comment: @MichaelHampton I can reach the service on port 8080 on my end of the tunnel, as long as I am in my local network, but not an HE's end of the tunnel.

Comment: @vidarlo I have tried taking the course, but I can't find a suitable IPv6 website to use for the tests. I have already contacted HE.

Comment: @neolith website?

Comment: @vidarlo http://[2a04:4540:7108:6d00:9071:6460:e7e0:10c]:8080 It is for a personal cloud server

Comment: HE's end of the tunnel 2001:470:6c:115::1/64

Comment: 2a04:4540:7100::/40 is not owned by HE. It's owned by a german ISP it seems. If you have Native IPv6, you don't need a HE tunnell. You are doing *something* wrong somewhere. However, Serverfault is for business related IT. I'd suggest asking at [superuser.com](https://superuser.com)

Comment: Yeah, but isn't that IPv6 going to change after some time or if my router restarts? I just want a static public IP. Where does it say Serverfault is only for businesses?

Comment: Then use a tunnel. But a tunnel means that you'll have to use IP's from the tunnels range, in your case 2001:470:6c:115::/64-net. Regarding scope for serverfault, please read [the On Topic-section in the help pages](https://serverfault.com/help/on-topic)